# I'm trying to get Role from back-end then use it in front-end but Angular can't read it after function

Tags: angular, typescript

```
public Role;
ngOnInit() {

    this.getRole()
    {
      this.roleserive.getrole(this.token)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.Role = res;
          console.log(this.Role)

        }
      )
    }
    console.log(this.Role)

   if(this.Role == 'emp')
   {
      this.getAllProjects();
   }
}
```

when i use console.log in function browser show the value of role but when i use it after function angular can't read the value of role

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43055706/1260204)

Comment: yes it's the answer of my question , thanks a lot